# Convert B-Spline into Bezier surfaces

Tags: algorithms, bezier-curve, spline

There is one topic regarding converting B-Spline curves into Bezier curves. (Given knots and control points),
[Convert a B-Spline into Bezier curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417859/convert-a-b-spline-into-bezier-curves)

I wonder if there is any way to convert(or partition) a B-Spline surface into Bezier patches. I have read
https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node19.html

That it is easy to extend the B-Spline to Bezier property to the surfaces. However, I am just a starter here, I don't know how to do it correctly, Are there any sources regarding the surface conversion between the two?